# Вызов c# функции в javascript файле в asp.net.mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Помогите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

js file:

```
 var    scannedImg = Q("#scanned-img"),
        scannedQR = Q("#scanned");
    var args = {
        resultFunction: function (res) {
            scannedImg.src = res.imgData;
            scannedQR[txt] = res.code;
            if (PageMethods.CalledMethod(res.code) = "Да") {
                document.location.replace("/Storekeeper.aspx");
            }
        },
```

c# file:

```
        [WebMethod()]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
        public static string CalledMethod(string v)
        {
            string variable = v;
            if (variable == "123")
            {
                return "Да";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Нет";
            }
        }
```

```
                            <div class="well" style="overflow: hidden;">
                                <img width="320" height="240" id="scanned-img" src="">
                            </div>
                            <div class="caption">
                                <h3>Scanned result</h3>
                                <p id="scanned"></p>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы ответить на вопрос "что я делаю не так?" надо сначала объяснить, что вы хотели сделать и что именно не получилось. В текущем виде на вопрос могут ответить только телепаты.

Comment: Извините пожалуйста. Я пытаюсь вызвать функцию c# в js файле, передав ему string значение, некоторые данные выводятся в html. Читал много форумов, один из методов решения было вызвать PageMethods с указанием функции, но он не работает. Собственно, я не понимаю в чем проблема(.

Comment: То, что вы привели в коде - это попытка использования Xml Web Service (о-очень старая технология), это не ASP.NET MVС. Вы поддерживаете очень старый проект? Тогда вопрос имеет смысл (но метка неправильная). Вы хотите освоить asp.net mvc? Тогда забудьте про WebMethod, ScriptMethod, PageMethods.

Comment: Я просто не понимаю как в asp net передать c# функцию в js. Видел как люди делают через ajax - не получается.

Comment: На самом деле мне нужно передать значение переменной из Javascript в C# файл, обработать это значение и вернуть обработанное значение обратно.

Comment: Ещё раз: то, что вы видели (и что вы используете в показанном коде) - очень старая технология. Сейчас её не используют. Вы действительно её хотите учить?

Comment: _Видел как люди делают через ajax_ - ну так делайте через ajax. Но вы-то используете какую-то фигню (устаревшую).

Comment: [Tutorial: Call an ASP.NET Core web API with JavaScript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - тут показано, как из JS обращаться к C# - вызывать методы контроллеров

Comment: [Call .NET methods from JavaScript functions in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0) - вот ещё вариант. Но, обратите внимание, - это Blazor. Я бы предостерёг от его использования, пока вы начинающий.